# Schema users and permissions

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

From the documentation I understood that the schemas are related to one user. I want to create 6 schemas that each will have its tables, but I want just one user that can connect through php and insert some data in those tables (will hace access to the other schemas).

I know you can just assign the CONNECT and RESOURCE roles to those users, but from what i read its not the best option regarding security.

I thought about making 2 roles, one for the schema users and another for the php user.

For the php user: GRANT CREATE SESSION, UNLIMITED TABLESPACE to 
For the schema users; but do i need some privileges for these users? Since they will not be accessed

Is this a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle each schema is also a user. You can lock users that you do not want people to log in to and then give the user that you want to login privileges on the objects in the other schemas.